# How can I see a preview of a tmux session/window from outside of tmux?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, tmux, fzf

While inside of tmux, I can press `PREFIX w`, which runs `tmux choose-tree`.
This brings up an interactive session/window/pane selector that also displays a
preview of the highlighted node.

From a normal shell outside of tmux, I can run `tmux attach -t '$1:1'` to attach
to any session or window by name or index (see `man tmux` section "Clients And
Sessions").

Is there command similar to `tmux attach -t` where I can pass in a session/window
name/index and see a preview of it, like to the one used in `tmux choose-tree`? Ideally this command would just show the lower portion of this
image:

[image: Running <code>tmux choose-tree</code>]

The goal here is to pipe a list of tmux windows from all sessions to
[`fzf`](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf), and pass a separate command in `fzf`'s
`--preview` flag to show a preview of the session/window currently highlighted
while fuzzy finding.

I have a draft working
[here](https://github.com/sh78/dotfiles/blob/8dd6552caeefcad2f17fd452385423a11a1e5846/.bin/fzft#L1).
It populates a preview with the session/window index in a tmux-compliant format
and will switch to the selected session.

Comment: Pretty good, choosing right in the pane's shell, less flicker when switching with `prefix s/w`.

Comment: You can use `tmux capture-pane -p | cat`, will create an answer once I create the script

Answer (score 5):

This can be partially implemented by means of this recent commit: https://github.com/tmux/tmux/commit/2628af573d98f7bdd4db02c7a80c860b867a45fb

I do so here: https://github.com/petobens/dotfiles/commit/c21c306660142d93d283186210ad9d301a2f5186 in order to get the following:
[image]

Comment: Nice, very clean interface. I learned a bunch about fzf and tmux reading your dotfiles.

Comment: Very nice. Here's my stab at taking it a bit further: https://github.com/von/homestuff/blob/main/home/dot_tmux/scripts/executable_tmux-preview.sh